# How to limt the digit size into single in python regex

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution, digit

I have a text file like below:

- INPUT.txt

  ```
  155    Phe  12xD,7xQ,5xE,5xG,4xA,4xS,2xF,2xH,2xI,2xK,1xM,1xN
  151    Glu  11xD,6xA,5xE,3xF,3xG,3xM,2xI,2xS,1xH,1xK,1xL,1xP
  159    Thr  15xF,6xL,6xM,5xG,5xI,5xT,4xA,4xV,3xR,1xD,1xN,1xP
  ```

Here, My aim is: To keep the numbers that comes above >=6 in 3rd colum:

So, What I did is:
I tried to replace 1x(Anyleter),2x(Anyleter),3x(Anyleter),4x(Anyleter),5x(Anyleter) by nothing through following script:

```
filepointer = open(filename,"r") # Reading file
text = filepointer.read()
merged = text.splitlines()
    for i in merged:
        print re.sub("[0-5]x[a-zA-Z]","", i.rstrip())#Replace 1x,2x,3x,4x,5x by nothing
```

OUTPUT:

```
155    Phe      2,7xQ # 2xD belong to 12xD replaced
151    Glu      1,6xA # 1xD belong to 11xD replaced
159    Thr      5,6xL,6xM # 5xF belong to 15xF replaced
```

Replacing on 1x,2x,3x,4x,5x is perfect but when **these 1x,2x,3x,4x,5x belong to 11x,12x,13x,14x,15x also getting replaced**. So I want to restrict this by replacing just a single digit not for more than single digit.

- **Expected OUTPUT**:

  ```
   155    Phe      12xD,7xQ
   151    Glu      11xD,6xA
   159    Thr      15xf,6xL,6xM
  ```

I hope my question is understandable.

**I just want to replace the 1 by nothing**

**not the 1 belong to 11,21,31,41 etc etc**

Thanking you in advance

Comment: I guess `re.sub(r"\b[0-5]x[a-zA-Z]\b","", i.rstrip())` should help. See [demo](http://ideone.com/6EXArO). Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Use word boundary [`\b[0-5]x[a-zA-Z]\b,?`](https://regex101.com/r/oM1cJ0/1)

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/6EXArO). Is it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r",?\b[0-5]x[a-zA-Z]\b","", s)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6EXArO)

The regex - `,?\b[0-5]x[a-zA-Z]\b` - features a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` so that <kbd>digit</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> must be preceded and followed by non-word characters (not `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and a comma is optional at the start (as `?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the preceding subpattern).

Also, please note that regular expressions are best declared using "raw" string literals (see `r""` notation). That way, we do not have to use double backslashes when using the word boundary.

Comment: Glad to help. Another alternative to regex101 with visualization: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/twunRDBz5Hkn1xW9)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go with function-

`reg.txt` contents is as below-

```
155    Phe  12xD,7xQ,5xE,5xG,4xA,4xS,2xF,2xH,2xI,2xK,1xM,1xN
151    Glu  11xD,6xA,5xE,3xF,3xG,3xM,2xI,2xS,1xH,1xK,1xL,1xP
159    Thr  15xF,6xL,6xM,5xG,5xI,5xT,4xA,4xV,3xR,1xD,1xN,1xP
```

---

```
p = r"C:\reg.txt"

f = open(p,'rb').readlines()
def changer(l):
    d= l.split(',')
    dd = d[1:]
    lst = ['6', '7', '8', '9']
    s = [i for i in dd if i[0]  in lst]
    s.insert(0,d[0])
    return ','.join(s)
for i in f:
    print changer(i)
```

Prints-

```
155    Phe  12xD,7xQ
151    Glu  11xD,6xA
159    Thr  15xF,6xL,6xM
```